# Attributing as B&W in IPTC using Bridge

Tags: metadata, black-and-white, adobe-bridge

As an amateur I organise my photos in Bridge which does everything I require apart from one thing, I cannot find a means of attributing the color mode. It is visible but not editable under the file properties and if the original setting was correct it displays B&W otherwise it is a default of RGB. I have been scanning a lot of older pictures and would like to differentiate between colour & B&W. I could be dilligent and ensure it is set correctly at the time of scanning but it is a bit late for that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When Bridge is showing an image that is B&W, that means that there is only one channel in the images. Only 256 shades of gray.  When you have a grayscale image that shows up as RBG, that means that even though the colors are all grayscale, the image was saved as a three channel RGB, 256 shades of red, 256 shades of blue, and 256 shades of green. But the values of the red, green, and blue are all equal.

Changing a grayscale RGB image into B&W is not something that can simply be changed by editing the metadata. That is why this shows up under "File Properties" in Bridge. It's a property of the file itself. The image has to be resaved as a one channel grayscale jpeg.

Comment: If re-saved as grayscale or dot gain the *color mode* will remain RGB; the *color profile* will then be grayscale/dot gain (if embedded).

Comment: Depends on what you do and what programs you use.  For example, to do so in Irfanview, you would have to convert to grayscale (Cntl+G).  Then when you save as jpeg, it will be a 1 channel grayscale jpg and should show up as B&W in Bridge.  I can't answer anything about dot gain.

Comment: It seems like it should show up as B&W in bridge, but it doesn't, it shows with the color mode of RGB, and a color profile of Dot Gain (single channel grayscale). B&W/grayscale is not a color space, and I think that is the issue... I have tried it several ways with several programs and it never shows with color mode of B&W; but I do not have Irfanview.

Comment: It sounds like the programs you are using are still saving it as an RGB image.  Here's an example in GIMP.  Use the Image Menu->Mode->Grayscale and export as jpeg.  The result shows up as B&W for me in Bridge.